# read from standard input into mmap

Tags: c

I have this loop that reads from standard input into the array

```
int* arr;
arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    read(0, &arr[i], 4);
}
```

How can I make it work if `arr` is a shared memory pointer `arr=createSharedMemory(sizeof(int)*size)`

```
int* createSharedMemory(size_t size) {
    int protection = PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE;
    int visibility = MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED;
    return (int*)mmap(0, size, protection, visibility, 0, 0);
}
```

currently it Segmentation Faults

Comment: You don’t show how you check that the memory mapping works. If that’s okay, the reading code should be okay.  Memory is just memory when all is said and done.

Comment: Some implementations require `fd` to be -1 with `MAP_ANONYMOUS`

Answer (score 3):

Check your return from `mmap()`.

You tried to `mmap()` stdin. Barring exotic environments, stdin is some kind of terminal or pipe, neither of which support memory mapped IO.

Try this sample:

```
int* createSharedMemory(size_t size) {
    int protection = PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE;
    int visibility = MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED;
    int *p = (int*)mmap(0, size, protection, visibility, -1, 0);
    if (p == (int*)(ptrdiff_t)-1) return NULL;
    return p;
}

arr = createSharedMemory(sizeof(int)*size);
if (arr == NULL) {
    perror("mmap");
    exit(3);
}
```

Incidentally, your read loop will explode if `sizeof(int) < 4` which is unlikely.